# Passing JSON data into div box

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've got a html page that retrieves JSON data from a website and then displays it in sections on the page when a button is clicked. What I want to do though is have all that data contained within a single box that has a scroll-bar if the contents  are too great. 
I know how to get the JSON data and I know how to display it, but my problem is I can't figure out how to add it to the 'mydiv' box on the page rather than just append it to the end of the page itself. I know I'm probably overlooking something very simple but I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I've spent all day toying around with this to try and get it to work without any results.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JSON scroller</title>
<script>

function dataget()
{
request= new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET","http://example.com/example.json",true);
request.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
        {
            alert(request.responseText);
            reply=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            new_nodes(reply);
        }
    }
request.send()
}
function new_nodes(nodes)
{
    var i
    for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
        new_node(nodes[i]);
}
function new_node(node)
{
    var sec=document.createElement("section");
    var head=document.createElement("h2");
    var par=document.createElement("p");
    sec.appendChild(head);
    sec.appendChild(par);
    head.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.title));
    par.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.summary));
    document.body.appendChild(sec)
}
</script>
<body>

<div id="myDiv" style="height:50%;width:50%;border:1px solid #ccc;overflow:auto;"> 
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="dataget();" />
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

I'm fairly certain that what I need to do is just change the 'new_node' function's append and create code to involve 'mydiv' but every alteration I've made has either resulted in the same results with the data being appended to the body or no results at all. Either that or I've been completely off this whole time.
Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is what the contents of the JSON file looks like

```
[
{ "title": "book1",
      "summary": "A fantasy novel set in medieval times." },
{ "tile": "Book2",
  "summary": "A scifi novel set on another planet."}
]
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your statements. with `;`..`var i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is set your myDiv html equal to your JSON.

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "whatever";
```

If you don't need to do anything to the JSON besides display it you could just change this:

```
function new_node(node)
{
  var sec=document.createElement("section");
  var head=document.createElement("h2");
  var par=document.createElement("p");
  sec.appendChild(head);
  sec.appendChild(par);
  head.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.title));
  par.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.summary));
  document.body.appendChild(sec)
}
```

To this:

```
    function new_node(node)
{
  var sec=document.createElement("section");
  var head=document.createElement("h2");
  var par=document.createElement("p");
  sec.appendChild(head);
  sec.appendChild(par);
  head.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.title));
  par.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.summary));
  document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(sec)
}
```

*Edited to better reflect OP intentions.*

Comment: He's trying to format the json data and enter them in proper elements. How to do know if json data contains html tags ?...I don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: That's worked. Thanks a bunch. Feeling pretty dumb for forgetting all about .getelementbyid

Answer (score 2):

its better if you do like this

```
function new_node(node)
{
    var sec=document.createElement("section");
    var head=document.createElement("h2");
    var par=document.createElement("p");
    sec.appendChild(head);
    sec.appendChild(par);
    head.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.title));
    par.appendChild(document.createTextNode(node.summary));
    //document.body.appendChild(sec);
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML =  sec ;
}
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="dataget();" />
<div id="myDiv" style="height:50%;width:50%;border:1px solid #ccc;overflow:auto;"> 
</div>
```

Comment: This will replace the Div's content with the node each time.